# pushing Dialog back to microsoft band after interacting with Cortana on Band

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I have developed an application and I use voice commands(Cortana integration) to get some data in my phone. Now I would like to add band support. I expect the similar function but I needs to push the data to my Band. I just spoke the same voice command through my band this time. Cortana opens my app and show me the data on phone. But what I need is that the same data should push to my band. I used "NotificationManager.SendMessageAsync with MessageFlags.ShowDialog" but it is not showing as dialog. I have to open the band tile to see the data. But I wanted to get a pop up and show me the data as usully bands do. Could any one help me out. Thanks in advance.

Note: An example is, when we ask about the "current whether" through Cortana, the result is displayed in the Band's screen.

Comment: Can any one please help? I think its because of Cortana dialog opens already and we cannot open two dialog one by one. After the app identify my voice command and if I dismiss cortana dialog, I am getting the Dialog I am pushing from code. Can we programmatically dismiss cortana's dialog?

Comment: Can any one please help me on this please...

Comment: Please include some code, along with what you've tried already (better formatted and clearer); repeated comments as to requesting help also don't improve your question's visibility so are pointless.

Comment: Hello Clint, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Actually it does not seems to be a code error. The problem is that - When I ask anything to Cortana through band, the default cortana "Listening..." window shows. This window is active in Band while my phone app is pushing to send a dialog to my Band. Because of this my dialog is not showing by default. Either I have to close the Cortana window before my dialog arrives to my band else I have to go to my tile and check for the new Message. Is there any way to show my dialog over Cortana's default window? I hope now its clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no means provided to show a Microsoft Band SDK dialog over the Cortana window on the Band in the SDK today. Your best bet would be to reach out to the Microsoft Band team at msbandsdk@microsoft.com with an explanation of your use case.

Comment: Thanks you very much Mark, I am goanna mark it Answered and I will get in touch with the Band team. Many thanks

Comment: Another location to ask questions of the Microsoft Band team would be: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/